# How do I read a file byte-by-byte in NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I've been wondering how to read a binary file byte-by-byte with `x86_64` assembly. Let's say I want to interpret those bytes as unsigned integers (from `0` to `255`). For example, for a file like `C0 01 A2` I would like my program's exit value to be `356`

I found a useful example of a simple `cat` implementation, right [here](https://gist.github.com/BertrandBordage/10921263). It reads the file in chunks of `2048` bytes and just prints them. Very straightforward.

My file, however, can contain zero bytes. A zero bytes, when seen in a string buffer, indicates end of string, which I cannot detect with that approach.

Is there an elegant (and hopefully not terribly inefficient) way of doing this? Maybe I'm overseeing a simple solution?

Comment: Neither `SYS_READ` nor the cpu itself is particularly bothered by zero bytes. If you don't treat it as end of string, then it's not end of string. You get the number of bytes read into the buffer, use that.

Comment: Jester is correct. That code you link to doesn't print until it finds a NUL character. It reads a file (and then writes it to the display) until SYS_READ returns 0 characters.

Comment: How `C0 01 A2` produces 163? (0xA2 = 162)

Comment: Well, apparently I can't add hex

Comment: So you are looking to read a binary file in chunks to sum all the bytes in the file? When your program exits the value returned to the shell can only be in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: @Ped7g: He appears to be summing the values. C0+01+A2 = 0x163 = 355 (I assume 356 was in error in the qyestion)

Comment: You really need to specify operating system.

Comment: @Gene: It's x86-64 Linux, based on the code linked from github.  I added the tag.

Comment: Call sys_read in chunks of 128kiB or so, then loop over that summing bytes with `psadbw` / `paddq` (and horizontal sum at the end).  Or if you are using it as the Linux process exit status, only the low 8 bits matters, so you can just use `paddb` to sum with wraparound at byte boundaries.

Comment: Why not just mmap the whole file, then add those bytes one by one? Like get the file size into rcx, write a loop to copy each byte into rbx, add it to rdi, after this, call exit. I don't know how that relates to zero byte or cat program.